# Posting pictures to Instagram using headless Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, instagram

I would like to upload a picture to Instagram using headless selenium, and I am running my app on an Ubuntu 18.04 server.

For the selenium part I have used [this solution](https://github.com/shriar/Insta-post/blob/master/post_Instapicture.py) and it works perfectly, however I cannot use `autoit` as it is Windows only, and even if it weren't, I'm not so sure I could still use it as I am going headless.
Sending the image path directly through selenium is not an option either, as Instagram doesn't have rendered file input fields. It probably just generates one when the post button is clicked but never adds it to the DOM.

Is there a way to remake what the solution I've linked above does without `autoit`?

Comment: I think you're better off investigating the instagram API than using the ui. You can find out more here: https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Comment: I investigated the Instagram API, and not only is the `instagram_content_publish` scope locked behind an application review, but they're also not accepting applicants for it, bringing me back to Selenium